# I can't ping 8.8.8.8 from 2960 L2 switch?

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, troubleshooting

I have new 2960 L2 switch, I can't ping 8.8.8.8 from switch but having internet on clients that connected to same switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an SVI with a proper IP address and mask for the VLAN, and you need to have the correct default gateway set for that SVI. The VLAN for that SVI needs to be allowed on the trunk(s) back to the router. Your switch will be just another host on the VLAN.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty normal. Looks like your switch doesn't have the default gateway set, try

`ip default-gateway <IP of your gateway>`

in the *enable* mode.

Since clients connected to this switch can reach Google public DNS, they have information on where to look for the gateway. Switch from the context of the network connectivity of it's management interface is an ordinary network host.